# How to properly escape \ character in c#?

Tags: c#, string, escaping

I have a string like,

```
var log = "C:\\folder\\folder2\\this.txt";
```

For some reason this does not escaped the backslash, it still shows the backslashes in the string as below:

```
C:\\folder\\folder2\\this.txt
```

How do I properly escaped the \ character to allow writing to a file at such a location?

Comment: in quick watch you see this

Answer (score 1):

You are looking at it in the debugger, There is no double back slash in actual string. The debugger shows it like that.

Do:

```
Console.WriteLine(log);
```

and it will display the string without double back slashes in the console.

Answer (score 1):

You are bound to see double backslashes if you're in the IDE, but they won't be there when you actually use the string.

As a bonus, you can rewrite your string as `var log = @"C:\folder\folder2\this.txt";`